# jquery :contains, :not(:contains) selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

A table-based calendar contains weeks with both a date and a number per each date:

```
    <tr>
       <td>6<p>16</p></td>
       <td>7<p>16</p></td>
       <td>8<p>16</p></td>
       <td>9<p>16</p></td>
       <td>10<p>16</p></td>
       <td>11<p>16</p></td>
       <td>12<p>16</p></td>
    </tr>
```

Using scripting like  `$(".table td:contains(0)").css({"background-color": "#900", "color": "white"});`  I want to select the color and background-color of all td's containing '0', but not '10', '20', or '30'.  At the same time, I want to select the color of all p's containing '0', but not '10'.

I've tried jquery's `:contains` and `:not(:contains)`, but don't know how to include multiple values in the `:not(:contains)` series to avoid css changes in the td's 10, 20 and 30 or the p's 10.

Ideas welcome.

Comment: `$(".table tr td:contains...` ?

Comment: You'd have better to use jq `filter()` method, validating it with a regex. That's said, you should provide example in question itself of what you are looking for, including expected behaviour. `I want to select the color and background-color of all td's containing '0', but not '10', '20', or '30'` So you want to select `0`, `40` or what?

Comment: Or, if you don't want to use filter, but you can get it so that every td has its value in an attribute (i.e. `<td data-date="6">6...`), you could use a selector like `.table td[data-date='0']`.

Comment: EDIT: i miss this part `calendar` so indeed i'm really not sure what you are expecting

Comment: Structure the html with classes and attributes that let you work with it's content more efficiently. Current approach is more code intensive than needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better of using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to go thru all the TDs and return the ones that met the condition.

- Create a [`clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) of each td
- Grab the content in the P
- Remove the P from the clone
- Now grab the content of the TD
- Return the TDs that met the condition

Below is a demo:

```js
var $tds = $("tr > td").filter(function() {

    var $td = $(this).clone();
    var p_content = parseInt($td.find("p").text(), 10);
    $td.find("p").remove();
    var td_content = parseInt($td.text(), 10);
    return !p_content || !td_content;
});

//Apply some CSS to the matched TDs
$tds.css({"background-color": "green"});

//Now find all the Ps with zero or less value
//and apply your CSS
$tds.find("p").filter(function() {
    return !parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
}).css({"color": "#fff"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>6<p>16</p></td>
       <td>0<p>16</p></td>
       <td>8<p>0</p></td>
       <td>9<p>16</p></td>
       <td>10<p>0</p></td>
       <td>11<p>16</p></td>
       <td>10<p>0</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The filter method looks to be best, but I'd better re-explain my needs: Since each month in my calendar table has dates in <td> and each month has the 10th, 20th, and 30th except Feb, I don't want those <td>'s background and colors changed, BUT I do want <td>'s with <p> containing 0 (zero) to change, AND I want the <p> to be white.  Hope this helps . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you did it using the [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) selector, you could chain them like so:

```
$(".table td:contains('0'):not(:contains(10)):not(:contains(20)):not(:contains(30))").css({"background-color": "#900", "color": "red"});
```

[(See Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7yvru3wa/1/)

However, this is really ugly and hard to read. I would suggest following 
@A. Wolff's advice and use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(".table td:contains(0)").filter(function() {
     return !/10|20|30/.exec($(this).text());
});
```

[(See Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7yvru3wa/2/)